# Workaround for systemverilog there is no `if compiler directive

Tags: if-statement, verilog, system-verilog, compiler-directives

In systemverilog there is no `if compiler directive. So the following lines are incorrect:

```
`define BITS 16

reg[`BITS-1:0] my_reg;

...
`if `BITS > 10
   my_reg[31] = 1'b0;
endif
...
```

Without `if there are warnings/errors.

How can I workaround or solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can a procedural `if` statement

```
if (`BITS > 10)
      my_reg[31] = 1'b0;
```

and the compiler/synthesizer will optimize out a branching statement with a constant expression; meaning no extra logic gets created by the `if` statement.

To get around the out-of-bound message, you need a more complex expression (still a constant)

```
my_reg[(`BITS>31) ? 31 : 0] = 1'b0;
```

Answer (score 0):

1800-2012 LRM, 22.5.1: *"The directive `define creates a macro for text substitution."* Eg.:

```
`define D(x,y) initial $display("start", x, y, "end");

`D( "msg1" , "msg2" ) // expands to 'initial $display("start", "msg1", "msg2", "end");'
```

For numerical parameters you should use `parameter` / `localparam` depending on your needs.